# Drive Tester for a Class Issues

Tags: java, class, oop, testing

I have been putting together a Drive Tester to test a class I have been working on for an assignment, but I have hit a dead end with the tester and I am not sure how to finish it up and remove any errors.

Here is the tester:

```
public class PersonTester 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("PersonClassTester");
    System.out.println("*****************");
    System.out.println("");

    Person joeSmith = new Person();
    String "smith" = joeSmith.setSurName(); // All these statements with set surname and forname etc are apperantly not statements and require a semi-colon, even though they are there.
    String "joe" = joeSmith.setForName();
    int 25 = joeSmith.setAge();
    double 1.57 = joeSmith.setHeight();
    String "male" = joeSmith.setGender();

    joeSmith.toString();
    joeSmith.format();
} 
}
```

The main issue with this is that the Netbeans client is stating that the setter statements highlighted are not actually statements, and are saying that it needs a semi-colon for each of them despite them actually being there. It is also saying that there are no formal or actual arguments. I know what they are but I'm getting confused on them regardless.

And this is the class I need to run through the tester:

```
public class Person 
{
private String surName;   
private String forName;   
private int age;   
private double height;           
private String gender;

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName() + "[surName= " + surName + " forName= " + forName + " age= " + age + " height= " + height + " gender " + gender + "]";
}

public void format()
{
    System.out.format("%10s%10s%10d%10f%10s", surName, forName, age, height, gender);
}

public String getSurName()
{
    return surName;
}

public String getForName()
{
    return forName;
}

public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public double getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public String getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

public void setSurName(String surName)
{
    this.surName = surName;
}

public void setForName(String forName)
{
    this.forName = forName;
}

public void setAge(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
}

public void setHeight(double height)
{
    this.height = height;
}

public void setGender(String gender)
{
    this.gender = gender;
}    
}
```

Any advice on getting the class tester to function properly? Once the tester works the rest of the assignment shouldnt be much of a problem.

Edit: The program compiles, but is unable to print the String statements.

```
PersonClassTester
*****************

surName   forName        25  1.570000    gender
```

Comment: The main class now compiles, but it seems like it won't generate the string statements, I will add what came out from the runt-time.

Comment: Nevermind, have got the statement working properly now, I had to remove the quotation marks from the format method in the Person Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter method looks like:

```
public void setSurName(String surName)
{
    this.surName = surName;
}
```

Which says your setter is not going to return anything and it expects one parameter which is of String type.

Now here's how you are using your setter method:

```
String "smith" = joeSmith.setSurName();
```

So here it means you are expecting a surname from setter which is one part of compiler error that you see. And as stated, it expects a string argument and you are not passing it and that's another part of compiler issue.

So you may want to change it to:

```
joeSmith.setSurName("smith");//similar changes with other setter method.
```

Which means, now you are passing string argument and not expecting anything in return by calling this method and hence Compiler would be happy with this.

Answer (score 2):

`String "smith" = joeSmith.setSurName();` is not correct syntax. It should look like this:

`joeSmith.setSurName("smith")`

This tells Java to execute the method `setSurName()` on the object `joeSmith`, with the given string as an argument.

The same goes for the rest of your assignments in `main`.